# Run time error '9' VBA

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I get the error 'Subscript Out of Range' when I run the following code; debug points me to the last line:

```
Dim SrcBook As Workbook
Dim TrgBook As Workbook
Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet
Dim TrgSheet As Worksheet
Dim Sheet_Name As String

Workbooks.Open (CalendarFile)
Sheet_Name = MonthName(Month(SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, "D").Value), False)
MsgBox ("Sheet_Name Value is: " & Sheet_Name)
Set TrgSheet = Workbooks(CalendarFile).Worksheets(Sheet_Name)
```

I have repeatedly verified that CalendarFile is a valid file name (I use the full path filename). Sheet_Name is also the valid name of a sheet in that Workbook. I get a similar error if I try to access the worksheets via numeric indexing [ie, Workbooks(CalendarFile).Worksheets(11) vs Workbooks(CalendarFile).Worksheets(November)]. The MsgBox call verifies that I'm feeding the WorkSheets() method the proper sheet name.

Lastly, ScrRow is properly defined - I am able to use this code to manipulate target WorkSheets in the same WorkBook as the macro is called from in toy/testing applications, but for some reason it is failing when I try to manipulate target WorkSheets in other (open) WorkBooks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: Sheet_Name should be `Range` and not string.

Comment: @Niclas why would it be a Range?  MonthName returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

If `CalendarFile` is a valid filename, that's your issue. The index you need for `Workbooks()` is the `Workbook.Name`, not its file path.  For example, if `CalendarFile` was `C:\Foo\Bar.xlsx`, you need to use `Bar.xlsx`.

As for the explanation above, it really doesn't matter because you should ***really*** just grab a the reference that `Workbooks.Open` returns and just use that:

```
Set TrgBook = Workbooks.Open(CalendarFile)
Sheet_Name = MonthName(Month(SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, "D").Value), False)
MsgBox ("Sheet_Name Value is: " & Sheet_Name)
Set TrgSheet = TrgBook.Worksheets(Sheet_Name)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually missed your post and discovered this after further tweaking my MsgBox statedments to find the error - I discovered that opening the workbook was itself the error, not indexing the Worksheets. Regardless, I'm glad you had my back.

Comment: @kapowpow - The takeaway should be that you should just collect `Workbook` the reference that `.Open` returns for you.  You should never have to even use `Workbooks()` in this situation.

Comment: And thank you for the syntax suggestion - I have implemented it. I had originally set it up that way, but changed it later because the macro I'm building was never functional and I was trying to understand why. I will change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, at least to this problem:

```
Workbooks.Open (CalendarFile)
```

Requires the full-path-name of the file to open, but further references to the file require just the file name - without any of the path attached. That is,

```
Workbooks(file_name_without_path.xlsx).Worksheets(Sheet_Name)
```

This is extremely annoying and should be fixed.

Comment: `Workbooks` is a collection of *open* workbooks. It doesn't work on closed files. You use Open to add items to the collection. It works as is --- nothing to fix.